# High Throughput but Slow Consumer (Event Grid or Servicebus)

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-eventgrid

My producer is producing high volume data in a short span of time for a couple hours of a day; then does nothing for the rest of the day. My consumer is slow due to the slowness of the relational db, often the consumer is crashed (function app) when load is in peak.

I want a cost effective solution.

1. If I use service bus + function app, behind the scene, the function app  polls the service bus and costs a lot.
2. Event grid is not sure if it is synchronous or will it deliver all the events to the consumer at once. If event grid is synchronous, I'll go with it.

Please suggest me the better approach. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Synchronous messaging with service bus would be a good option but
  since event grid can be use as cost effective alternative.
- Use custom discrete event as they are better for scalability.  Also,
  as the name suggest the event grid is event driven thus it is
  synchronous.
- If one of you are experiencing throttling issues, you can subscribe
  to the events with a Service Bus queue and start pulling the messages
  from there.

refer the following [article](https://yourazurecoach.com/2021/08/11/azure-service-bus-vs-event-grid/) to better explanation on difference service bus and event grid.
refer documentation of [event grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview) .